# How to show a related_name field from Django models connected through a ManyToMany relationship?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

New to Django and relational DBs. I'm building the classic Doctor appointment booking app and have come to a point where I don't know what to do. I've created the Doctor model pointing to a Clinic, but in my API the Clinic model won't show a list of all Doctors. How could I achieve this?

```
class Clinic(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Doctor(models.Model):
    clinic = models.ManyToManyField(Clinic, related_name="doctors")
```

```
class ClinicSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Clinic
        fields = '__all__'

class DoctorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Doctor
        fields = '__all__'
```

```
class ClinicViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Clinic.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ClinicSerializer

class DoctorViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Doctor.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DoctorSerializer
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django will automatically create the link from `Clinic` to `Doctor`. You don't need to (shouldn't) define it. From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#related-objects):

> Django also creates API accessors for the “other” side of the relationship – the link from the related model to the model that defines the relationship. For example, a `Blog` object `b` has access to a list of all related `Entry` objects via the `entry_set` attribute: `b.entry_set.all()`.

The [`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) argument that you passed to `ManyToManyField` when you created the `clinic` field is the name of the relation from `Clinic` to `Doctor`. It is optional and if you didn't pass it, it would be the lower-cased named of the model + `_set` - `doctor_set` in your case.

Usually you would set it to a plural in the case of `ManyToManyField`. In your case: `doctors`.

Because you have `related_name="doctor"` currently, you can retrieve a clinic's doctors with: `clinic.doctor.all()`.

Comment: Thank you! I guess I have the right relation then. I am using Django Rest Framework to get the data from the models but the list of doctors won't show up. I'm going to edit my question to reflect that.

Comment: I have accepted as the right answer as I realised the edited question was too different from the original one. I'll post a new question.